# Why UTF 8 Support for Jfreechart Dataset not working?

Tags: java, utf-8, fonts, jfreechart

I am creating `JFreeChart` by following method:

```
chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D
           ("", // chart title
            "", // domain axis label
            "",
            dataset, // data                
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, // orientation
            false, // include legend
            true, // tooltips?
            false // URLs?
            );
```

[image]

My dataset contains UTF-8 characters including chinese,japanese,hindi..etc.
so in tables data under the graph it shows data properly whatever language it comes  in.
But in case of graph it is showing Just square brackets..
Please help me how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a font that has glyphs for those characters, otherwise the system will just render them as empty box placeholders.

Comment: @David.. i used different fonts like sans-sarif,Arial Halvetica...etc..but the problem is that i m creting the chart by calling the method of ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(...) .. and even though it is showing me square boxes..even my dataset is UTF-8 compliant that is whatever i m adding to dataset is in already UTF-8 format.